# Transforming raw timeseries data into an organized dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I have a Covid-19 dataset containing information for each state of Brazil. The dates are the same for all states.

```
   region   state  date         newCases   cumulativeCases  newDeaths   cumulativeDeaths
1  Norte     RO 30/01/2020          0               0           0                0
2  Norte     RO 31/01/2020          0               0           0                0
3  Norte     RO 01/02/2020          0               0           0                0
4  Norte     RO 02/02/2020          0               0           0                0
5  Norte     RO 03/02/2020          0               0           0                0
6  Norte     RO 04/02/2020          0               0           0                0
```

I need to transform this data into a cases (or deaths) matrix with states in rows and dates in columns, like this:

[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cbh8.png)

I was able to do this using a for loop but I'm looking for a more simple and efficient way to do this task. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Will you be doing this once, or will you want to update this transformation of the data on an ongoing basis, as new data becomes available.

Comment: Thank you! For now, I only need to do this once.

Comment: The answer given below by starja is good direction. Tidy Data site will teach you basic principles of getting any data into an easy to manipulate and use in R (or other packages). You may need to download and add the tidyr package first to be able to do what is suggested in R your end.  If you are doing this only once, and the learning curve proves to much re your time, you could manipulate this data into what you want in a spreadsheet, then re import into R as a work around. Though I encourage you to persist with the learning more. Long term best, new skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your data is in the long format for one result variable (e.g. newCases or new Deaths) and you want to have it in the wide format. You may want to check out information about [tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html).
Do to this, you can use the function `pivot_wider` from the `tidyr` package:

```
data <- data.frame(state = rep(c("RO", "AC"), each = 5),
                   date = rep(seq(as.Date("2020/01/30"), by = "day", length.out = 5), times = 2),
                   newCases = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 5, 4, 0, 10))
head(data)
  state       date newCases
1    RO 2020-01-30        0
2    RO 2020-01-31        0
3    RO 2020-02-01        0
4    RO 2020-02-02        1
5    RO 2020-02-03        2
6    AC 2020-01-30        0

data_wide <- tidyr::pivot_wider(data = data,
                                names_from = date,
                                values_from = newCases)
head(data_wide)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  state `2020-01-30` `2020-01-31` `2020-02-01` `2020-02-02` `2020-02-03`
  <fct>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 RO               0            0            0            1            2
2 AC               0            5            4            0           10
```

You find more information about pivotting [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html).